# Determinant of vectors after embedding into high-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the $k$-dimensional (real) vector space $\mathbb R^k$. For any vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k \in \mathbb R^k$, we can define the determinant of these vectors as usual:

$$ \Delta = \det(v_1,\dots,v_k) $$

Now suppose that I have got an isometric embedding $phi : \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and all I know are the images of the original vectors:

$$ \phi(v_1), \dots, \phi(v_k) $$

How can I recover the original determinant $\Delta$ only knowing $\phi$ and the embedded vectors? Of course, one possibility is to compute the pseudoinverse of the linear mapping $phi$, but I wonder whether easier formulas exist.

For example, we know that

$$ \Delta^2 = \det\big( \phi(v_i) \cdot \phi(v_j) \big)_{1 \leq i,j \leq k} $$

which recovers the absolute value of $\Delta$. However, this does not recover the sign.

Comment: Ben already answered your question, but I thought it might be useful to note the reason is because the sign is capturing the *orientation* of the vectors within the original space, which is not captured by the other data.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to recover the sign. For example, if the embedded vectors are the columns of
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0},
$$
then we could write $A = BC$ with either
$$
B = B_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0}, \quad C = C_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
or
$$
B = B_2 = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1\\0&0}, \quad C = C_2 = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}.
$$
Note that $\det(C_1)$ and $\det(C_2)$ have opposite signs. In other words, the embedded vectors (the columns of $A$) are not enough to determine the sign of the determinant of the original vectors (the determinant of the matrix $C$).